# NG0303: Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'ion-range'

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, binding, directive, ng-modules

i'm started a few day ago with Ionic with angular project.
I had a problem when i serve my project.
this is the error: NG0303: Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'ion-range'.

I want to use the brightness puglin with ion-range.
Here my code.

app.module.ts

```
  import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';
import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { Brightness } from '@ionic-native/brightness/ngx';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule,IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule],
  providers: [{ provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },Brightness],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I have folder commons with a few random components, and a randomer.module to manage them.

in the randomer.module.ts

```
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NumberRandomComponent } from './number-random/number-random.component';
import { ActionsheetComponent } from './actionsheet/actionsheet.component';
import { BrightnessComponent } from './brightness/brightness.component';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [NumberRandomComponent,ActionsheetComponent,BrightnessComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,IonicModule
  ],
  exports:[NumberRandomComponent,ActionsheetComponent,BrightnessComponent]
})
export class RandomerModule { }
```

and my brigthness.component.html

```
  <p>
  brightness works!
 
  Current brightness level is {{ brightnessModel }} / 1
</p>
<ion-item>
  
    <ion-range min="0" max="1" step="0.01" [(NgModel)]="brightnessModel" (ionChange)="adjustBrightness()" [value]="brightnessModel">
      <ion-icon size="small" slot="start" name="sunny"></ion-icon>
      <ion-icon slot="end" name="sunny"></ion-icon>
  </ion-range>
 
</ion-item>
```

brightness.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Brightness } from '@ionic-native/brightness/ngx';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-brightness',
  templateUrl: './brightness.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./brightness.component.scss'],
})
export class BrightnessComponent implements OnInit {

  public brightnessModel = 0.20;

  constructor(private brightness: Brightness,) {
    // Set brightness on app load
   this.brightness.setBrightness(this.brightnessModel);
  }

  adjustBrightness(){
    // Called method from range's ionChange event
    this.brightness.setBrightness(this.brightnessModel);
  }
  ngOnInit() { }

}
```

here i import my randomer.module. on tab1.module.ts:

```
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Tab1Page } from './tab1.page';
import { ExploreContainerComponentModule } from '../explore-container/explore-container.module';

import { Tab1PageRoutingModule } from './tab1-routing.module';
import { RandomerModule } from '../commons/randomer.module';
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    IonicModule,
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ExploreContainerComponentModule,
    Tab1PageRoutingModule,
    RandomerModule
  ],
  declarations: [Tab1Page]
})
export class Tab1PageModule {}
```

and in tabPage.html i have:

```
<app-brightness></app-brightness>
```

I don't understand how to solve the problem.

Comment: NgModel is used in forms, not as you are using it. You are already setting the value also to this variable in your ion-range tag. Just remove the NgModel.

Comment: but if i leave NgModel i can't see the variation of the brightness

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to import `RandomerModule` inside your `app.module`
**app.module.ts:**

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule,IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule, RandomerModule], // <============== RandomerModule here.
  providers: [{ provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },Brightness],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

`FormsModule` within your `RandomerModule`

**randomer.module.ts:**

```js
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NumberRandomComponent } from './number-random/number-random.component';
import { ActionsheetComponent } from './actionsheet/actionsheet.component';
import { BrightnessComponent } from './brightness/brightness.component';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [NumberRandomComponent,ActionsheetComponent,BrightnessComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,IonicModule,FormsModule // <=== FormsModule here
  ],
  exports:[NumberRandomComponent,ActionsheetComponent,BrightnessComponent]
})
export class RandomerModule { }
```

And these setter/getter method to your brightness component.ts.

**brightness.component.ts:**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Brightness } from '@ionic-native/brightness/ngx';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-brightness',
  templateUrl: './brightness.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./brightness.component.scss'],
})
export class BrightnessComponent implements OnInit {

  
  private _brightnessModel = 0.20;  // <=== modified this
  public get brightnessModel() {    // <=== add this setter
      return this._brightnessModel;
  }

  public set brightnessModel(num: number) {  // <=== add this getter
      this._brightnessModel = num;
      this.brightness.setBrightness(num); 
  }

  constructor(private brightness: Brightness,) {
    // Set brightness on app load
   this.brightness.setBrightness(this.brightnessModel);
  }

  adjustBrightness(){
    // Called method from range's ionChange event
    // this.brightness.setBrightness(this.brightnessModel);
  }
  ngOnInit() { }

}
```

**brightness.component.html:**

Now remove the `(ionChange)="adjustBrightness()"` line

Comment: Thank you for the suggest but it doesn't work. The range appear on the html but when i move the spin for decrease or increase the brightness nothing happens...I follow a few video online and everyone have the same code...

Comment: This might be a long shot but try importing `Tab1PageModule ` in your AppModule

Comment: how send the new value of brightness from html to brightness.component.ts, by ngModule or something else?

Comment: You are on the right track with using `[(NgModel)]` for that. The issue here is the **brightness.component.ts** cannot detect FormsModule. If the above doesn't work, try importing `FormsModule` in the `RandomerModule` (given that you have `RandomerModule` imported in `AppModule`).

Comment: I added FormsModule on RandomModule and [(NgModel)] now don't give a problem, but in my emulator the brightness doesen't change...

Comment: I just updated my answer again, let me know if that helps!

Comment: oh wow! you solved the problem!! Thank youuu! Great